# Sphinx search in product params table (product attributes)

Tags: sql-server, search, sphinx

Good day!

I have some troubles in my sphinx search. I want to search in product params, but can't understand how can I do this.

For example.

**Products table**

```
product_id INT
product_name STRING
```

**Product Params table**

```
param_id INT
product_id INT
param_name STRING
param_value STRING
```

And this data for example:

**Products**

```
1 TV
2 Player
```

**Params**

```
1 1 Size Big
2 1 Color Red
3 1 Weight 3.0
4 2 Size Small
5 2 Color Brown
6 2 Length 20
```

And I want to search all products where **Size Is Small** OR **Color Is Red**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways. Perhaps one of the simplest:

```
sql_query = SELECT product_id, product_name, \
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(param_name,'_',param_value)) AS params \
   FROM products LEFT JOIN params USING (product_id) \
   GROUP BY product_id \
   ORDER BY NULL
```

(Thats actully mysql query, but sql-server cant be that much different)

Can then just do (SphinxQL) queries like

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('keyword @params (Size_Small | Color_Red)');
```

(if any of your params have spaces, might need to use REPLACE to change to understores, to keep them as one word - or use "phrase syntax")

Comment: Thanks a lot! And... Can I Sort query by param values, or compare. For example: I need all TV, where Screen > 24 etc.

Comment: No. This is making them feilds, which are limited to exact matching in the full-text search. For sorting, or for range queries, would need to use attributes. Using JSON attributes is probably the easiest, but might not perform that well, dont really know.